# Show that $\binom{1/2}{k} = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

**The Problem**

Show that

$$\binom{1/2}{k} = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}$$

**My Work**

$$\begin{align*}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k} &= \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k)!}{4^k(2k-1)(k!)^2}\\\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k)(2k-1)(2k-2)\cdots(k+1)}{4^k(2k-1)(k!)}\\\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k)(2k-2)\cdots(k+1)}{4^k(k!)}\\\\
&= \frac{(-1)(2k)(2k-2)\cdots(k+1)}{(k!)}\times \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^k
\end{align*}$$

I basically don't know where to go from here. My denominator is almost right where I want it to be, my numerator is fairly out of order though. Any suggestions on what I should try next, or if I should take a different approach all together?

Comment: you are almost there! multiply numerator and denominator by $(2k-1)k!$

Comment: @DavidHolden doesn't that take me two steps back?

Comment: yes! i started at the other end and failed to observe the direction of the traffic. apologies. a good example of a worse-than-useless suggestion. glad you've got the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: It’s very often a good idea to play with *both* sides, trying to get them to meet in the middle. In this case it’s a good idea to begin expanding the lefthand side:

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{1/2}k&=\frac{\left(\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)\ldots\left(-\frac{2k-3}2\right)}{k!}\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(2k-3)(2k-5)(2k-7)\ldots(3)(1)}{2^kk!}\;.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

Now go back and take another look at the result of your first step in manipulating the righthand side:

$$\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k)!}{4^k(2k-1)(k!)^2}\;.\tag{2}$$

Clearly $(-1)^{k+1}=(-1)^{k-1}$. The denominator of $(1)$ suggests splitting the denominator of $(2)$ as $(2^kk!)\cdot\big((2k-1)2^kk!\big)$ and trying to cancel the $(2k-1)2^kk!$ with something in the numerator. Thus, it looks as if you want to try to prove that

$$(2k-3)(2k-5)(2k-7)\ldots(3)(1)=\frac{(2k)!}{(2k-1)2^kk!}\;.$$

This isn’t too hard; try to combine $2^kk!$ in the denominator into a single product of $k$ integers.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for all the effort in this answer. Expanding the $(2k)!$ I see an easy cancellation for $(2k-1)$ there is also an easy cancellation for $k!$ but if I use that, I'm left without half of the LHS numerator and I still have a $2^k$ to take care of on the bottom

Comment: @Dunka: You’re welcome. *Don’t* cancel the $k!$ in the obvious way: combine it with the $2^k$ first. You have $k$ factors of $2$, and $k$ factors in $k!$, ...

Comment: I was trying to prove that $2^kk!$ would cancel out all the even cases in the denominator expansion with induction, then had a big "OOOOOO" moment as to why it made sense intuitively (anything(integers) multiplied by 2 is even. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dunka: Yep, you got it! You’re welcome!